# override the mat file when using "continue" calculation in Dymola

Tags: modelica, dymola

I tried to use the "continue" calculation in Dymola, but it doesn't generate a new .mat file, which makes it hard to store the data I need. 
My question is:
How could I override the .mat file when using continue calculation in Dymola?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot set the file-name when using Continue (which is the same as Continue>Continue).
However, you can:

1. Import the final values using Continue>Import Initial and selecting dsfinal.txt
2. Simulating as normal. If you want a different file-name for the result it can be changed in Simulation Setup>General>Result

Comment: The problem is that when I use Continue, it won't generate the .mat file for the Continue calculation. Assuming I do simulation during 0-1s, so when I do Continue, the simulation should be during 1-2s, but in the .mat file, there is no data related to 1-2s.

Comment: As I recall the file-name for Continue is "dsres.mat"; not the chosen one. (2 lines above in your screenshot.)